# My PIL (Pillow) is outputting as NoneType

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, discord, discord.py

So I have this code:

```html
    avurl = str(ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
    avurl = avurl.replace("?size=1024", "")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(avurl) as second_image:
            image_bytes = await second_image.read()
    with Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)) as first_image:
        output_buffer = BytesIO()
        first_image.save(output_buffer, "png")
        output_buffer.seek(0)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://i.imgur.com/dNS0WJO.png") as second_image:
            image_bytes = await second_image.read()
    with Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)) as second_image:
        output_buffer = BytesIO()
        first_image.save(output_buffer, "png")
        output_buffer.seek(0)
    first_image.paste(second_image, (0, 0))
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    first_image.save(buf, "png")
    file = discord.File(fp=first_image, filename="pfp.png")
    if arg1 is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title=" ", color=0xD1661E)
        embed.set_author(name="Your Profile", icon_url=url1)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://pfp.png")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed, file=file)
```

i'm trying to take two images, one being the user's discord profile picture, and then layering a png with transparency on it. the avatar url gives a .webp but documentation says PIL can handle .webp files.
i loaded in both imagesd with BytesIO, put them into PIL, pasted them together, and i'm getting this error:

```html
Ignoring exception in command profile:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Nik\anaconda3\envs\beatsbot\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 166, in load
        seek = self.load_seek
    AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_seek'
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Nik\anaconda3\envs\beatsbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
        ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:/Users/Nik/PycharmProjects/beatsbot/beats.py", line 2711, in profile
        first_image.paste(second_image, (0, 0))
      File "C:\Users\Nik\anaconda3\envs\beatsbot\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1483, in paste
        im.load()
      File "C:\Users\Nik\anaconda3\envs\beatsbot\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 169, in load
        seek = self.fp.seek
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Nik\anaconda3\envs\beatsbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
      File "C:\Users\Nik\anaconda3\envs\beatsbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
        await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Nik\anaconda3\envs\beatsbot\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

so it must be NoneType, but i have no idea why. i'm pretty sure i loaded everything in correctly, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard for me to reproduce this, however this part looks weird.

```
with Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)) as second_image:
     output_buffer = BytesIO()
     first_image.save(output_buffer, "png")
     output_buffer.seek(0)
```

This is the second time you called `first_image.save()` but I expected this block to call `second_image.save()`

Sorry if this was just bad interpretation of the code.